# Hide rows according to range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, range

Good day, I would love to ask you a question.

I have two colls with numbers and I need to compare first coll (longer) with second coll (shorter) and if there is a match, hide the row where the match occurs.

I have this so far:

```
Sub RowHide()
Dim cell As Range
Dim CompareCells As Range

Set CompareCells = Range("I2:I18")

For Each cell In Range("A2:A200")
    If cell.Value = CompareCells Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

My problem is that I don't know how to set value of CompareCells to start comparing. I'll appreciate every advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into both of yours ideas and converted them into one and I finally get it working.

Here is my final code:

```
Sub RowHide()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 2 To 197

Set FirstRange = Range("A" & i)

  For j = 2 To 18

    If FirstRange.Value = Cells(j, 8).Value Then
       FirstRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
  Next j

Next i
End Sub
```

Only modification if someone wants to use it is that you have to change numbers in for cycles according to number of rows in columns.

Thanks to both of you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set 2 separate ranges and compare them. If you want every cell compared with the one on the same line (A1 with B1, A2 with B2, etc) then consider using:

```
for i = 1 to something

    set cell1 = range("A" & i)
    set cell2 = range("B" & i)
    if cell1.value = cell2.value then
        'Do this, and do that!
        cell1.entirerow.hidden = true
    end if

next i
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Sub RowHide()
    Dim Longer As Range
    Dim i As Double
    i = 2 'Initial row
    For Each Longer In Range("A2:A200")
        If Longer.Value = Cells(i,2).Value Then
            Longer.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

PS:
Cells(RowIndex, ColumnIndex).Value: returns the value of the Row And Column.
ColumnIndex => Column A = 1, Column B = 2, an so on...